# Getting video Rotation metadata value using JavaCV

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, mp4, javacv

It seems there are lots of related topics out there, but I was not able to find the answer I'm searching for.

I'm using JavaCV and FFmpegFrameGrabber to get an image from the middle of the video. If an mp4 file has a "Rotation" metadata field (like 90 or 270), I'm getting an image that is positioned not correctly. I wanted to get Orientation from FFmpegFrameGrabber, but could not find a way to do so.

Is there a way to tell FFmpegFrameGrabber to respect orientation, or is there a way to get this value somehow using JavaCV?

Just in case the code that I have so far

```
    FFmpegFrameGrabber g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(input);
    g.start();
    g.getVideoMetadata(); // <-- this thing is empty

    try {
        g.setFrameNumber(g.getLengthInFrames() / 2);

        Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
        Frame frame = g.grabImage();

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = converter.convert(frame);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", output);
    } finally {
        g.stop();
    }
```

Comment: Is FFmpegFrameGrabber just a wrapper for the `ffmpeg` command-line interface tool?

Comment: Not really, it uses ffmpeg native library and JNI bindings. Of course, in the worst case I could install ffmpeg on the target machine, but I would like to avoid such an additional dependency. Plus invoking ffmpeg as a separate process is not as "nice" as using native Java

Comment: 3 years later...ever figure this one out?  I just ran into exactly the same thing.  The grabber's metadata property is always empty.